# How to make Streaming uploaded videos consistent given different sizes/aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-camera, exoplayer

I have users uploading videos and others watching it (like facebook/instagram ..etc). My question is how is it done that all videos is shown on every device not cropped and occupying the same dimension exactly. The uploader will upload  a video based on his camera (so no video will have the same dimension/aspect ratio). How does it always look the same (ie in terms space occupied, not stretched) on every device?

Thank you

Comment: Any love for this question?

Comment: It's kind of impossible. Some services do actually crop the video, others add margins. Often, they use a mixed strategy: some videos are cropped, others are augmented.

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn but for example Instagram/Facebook, whatever video you upload, is seen exactly on the other end as uploaded